# Selenium выбрать элемент по его содержимому

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'elfinder-cwd-filename')[0].click()
```

Таким образом я нажимаю на элемент с классом `elfinder-cwd-filename`

а как мне нажать на элемент который содержит в себе определенный текст, например:

```
<a class=elfinder-cwd-filename" > click1 </a>
```

как нажать на элемент в котором написано click1?